# Sonarlint warn if an object is used in java code base

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube, sonarlint

Can someone let me know how can I raise a sonar warning if an object is used in java code base? For example, let's say I have an object

```java
public class TukWebClient extends WebClient {
     ...
}
```

So I want to raise a warning if someone is using `WebClient` instead of `TukWebClient`. Can someone let me know if this can be achieved via Sonarlint? If not is there any other easier way to enforce this check?

- Java - 11
- Maven - 3.8.4

Comment: Sounds more like a job for something like https://www.archunit.org/ or JQAssistant? But I'm not 100% sure if you can't create a rule in SonarQube

Comment: It is not source code problem, it is what you want to analyse, therefore you have to find out guide about how edit sonarlint rules, if it was sonar qube server you would add the rule by UI, I think something like that about sonarlint